# Unable to Capture screen shot in react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video, react-native-view-shot

react-native Platform:

- iOS
- Android

Issue:

I am trying to capture screen. when video is pause. But whenever I trying to capture image from video. its throwing waring and unable to capture that;

**Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 25):
Error: The content size must not be zero or negative. Got: (0, 410)**

> Library version:

```
"react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
"react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
```

Code:

```
 const viewShotRef = useRef(null);
 const [uri, setUri] = useState('');

<ViewShot
      style={[styles.imageViewerStyleVideo, {height: 410}]}
      ref={viewShotRef}
      captureMode="continuous"
      options={{format: 'jpg', quality: 0.9}}>
         <Video
             ref={(p) => {
               videoRef = p;
         }}
         paused={isPaused}
         source={getImageSource(caseViewerVideo)}
         resizeMode={'contain'}
         selectedVideoTrack={'auto'}
         style={styles.fullScreenMode}
         controls={true}
         playInBackground={false}
         playWhenInactive={false}
      />
</ViewShot>

<Pressable
        style={{
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderRadius: 20,
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 260,
          right: 80,
          borderColor: Colors.pencil,
          backgroundColor: Colors.shadow,
        }}
        onPress={() => onCapture()}
 />

const onCapture = async () => {
    const uri = await viewShotRef.current.capture();
    setUri(uri);
    console.log(uri);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [github page](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot):

> "continuous" is EXPERIMENTAL, this will capture A LOT of images continuously. For very specific use-cases.

From your code I saw that you have a `Pressable` to make the screen shot. I would suggest you to completely remove `captureMode` props.

On faq I read:

**Getting "The content size must not be zero or negative."**

> Make sure you don't snapshot instantly, you need to wait at least
> there is a first onLayout event, or after a timeout, otherwise the
> View might not be ready yet. (It should also be safe to just wait
> Image onLoad if you have one). If you still have the problem, make
> sure your view actually have a width and height > 0.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the ViewShot component that will wait the
> first onLayout.

So maybe you should wait `Video`'s `onLoad` event before make a screen shot (another reason that suggest you to remove `captureMode` props).

Alternatively, you could use `captureRef(view, options)` or `captureScreen()` instead of `capture()`.

Comment: captureRef and captureScreen do not work with Video for some reason.  They just return a black empty image.  There are multiple bug reports/feature requests on this repo regarding this issue... I'm looking for a solution to this issue, but haven't found one yet.